# Accessing Object information in Javascript with a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't seem to understand how to access an objects value properly.

My object:

```
  // countrycode: "Radio station name"
  var radioStations = {
    fi: "Foo",
    hu: "Bar",
    am: "Baz"
  };
```

Then I have a variable called `code` which comes from a jQuery plugin, and has the countrycode of the country the user is mouseovering on a vector map.

I'd need to use `code` to add the radio stations name into the tooltip in here:

> ```
> onLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
>   if ( code in radioStations ) {
>     label.text(radioStations.code); // <- doesn't work
>   } else  { // hide tooltips for countries we don't operate in
>     event.preventDefault();
>   }
> },
> ```

Comment: radioStations.code -> JavasScripts looks for property 'code' of object radioStations, better radioStatios[code] code is then evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to us array notation to access the object by a variable. Try this:

```
onLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
    if (code in radioStations) {
        label.text(radioStations[code]);
    } 
    else  { 
        event.preventDefault();
    }
},
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xk8tg/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
onLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
  if(radioStations[code]) {
   label.text(radioStations[code]);
  } else {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/js4kq/1/)